# JavaScript libraries works fine in Rails development env but not in Heroku production

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, development-environment

I have JavaScript creating some sliders and a meter, which I'm going to be wiring up to a database/algorithms to create a profit optimization system for SMEs+. The sliders use the jQuery UI library, while the meter uses the justguage.js library.

```
<% provide(:title, "The SimutronX") %>
    <h1>The SimutronX</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <% for i in 0..5 do %>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <div class="selector"></div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <div id="profitGauge" class="100x120px"></div>
    </div>
    <%= javascript_tag do %>
    var g = new JustGage({
      id: "profitGauge",
      value: 67,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      title: "Profit"
    });
    $( ".selector" ).slider({
      orientation: "vertical"
    });
    <% end %>
```

Both of these work fine in [development](https://rails-tutorial-brotherlongtail.c9users.io/simutronx). After testing these in development I pushed to [production](https://boiling-dawn-38516.herokuapp.com/simutronx) in order to show the client my progress.

```
git add -A
git commit -m "add basic dials/meter"
git push 
git push heroku
```

On pushing to Heroku I receive an error which I was getting with a previous JavaScript library, `jquery.knob.min.js`.

[image: SimutronX]

What's happening here? I've not really used Heroku much, so I don't understand why it would be reacting [differently](https://boiling-dawn-38516.herokuapp.com/simutronx) to my remote development environment.

[This](https://rails-tutorial-brotherlongtail.c9users.io/assets/application.js) is the link to my development application.js. In production I am unsure how to access this file.

Comment: It looks like jQuery Knob's HTML page is getting bundled into your JS. I would guess your production build step is also bundling html into your JS, but hard to tell. Check your js https://boiling-dawn-38516.herokuapp.com/assets/application-18654010ec56db7dab7e5b8f7618864a2ca437c9ce8087297c26c04f0c8367a7.js

Comment: Why would it still be getting bundled after I deleted it? If it was still getting bundled why would my dev environment work fine?

Comment: Do you have a different local/dev/prod build setup? In your JS you can see the HTML is bundled in there: https://boiling-dawn-38516.herokuapp.com/assets/application-18654010ec56db7dab7e5b8f7618864a2ca437c9ce8087297c26c04f0c8367a7.js

Comment: I'm using cloud9 as a development environment. I have pushed to Heroku from there via git as detailed above. Though as I explained I'm not sure I fully understand Heroku yet as I only just started using it.

Comment: looks like there is a syntax error in your application.js, could we see what is that about?

Comment: maybe application.js isn't compiling properly! Good suggestion!! If so that would make it definitely a Rails issue, and we could raise it on their GitHub. I'll add my full applications.js so we can take a look.

Comment: If you click on that link `application-1865401...js-1578` it should take you to the syntax error so you can see if it is a syntax error in the code.. Anyway I was able to solve the problem i had with jquery-ui. The gem was not actually loading correctly jquery and once I downloaded the jquery files it fixed. Just a tip, **if you want to reply to somebody** and have them know, you should use @RailsKiddie or @mrsq ..